# DirectShow filter that scales up the framerate of a video

Tags: video, filter, directshow, video-processing, frame-rate

I'm currently working on a software that is simultanously recording two videos. The first one has a framerate of 25fps, the second has a framerate of 10fps (or maybe 15fps in the future). Later, these two videos are put together into one video with a picture in picture. The problem is, that the DirectShow Filter for picture in picture doesn't support videos with different framerates. Now I'm looking for a DirectShow filter that can produce "dummy frames" to scale up the framerate of the second video to 25fps. Does anyone know such a DirectShow filter?

Thanks in advance, David

Comment: No stock filter for this, you will need to create it or use a third party solution if such exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the frame rate converter

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819100(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I notice that this answer has been voted unhelpful. Can the voter please explain the reason? I haven't tried the frame rate converter itself, but have tried a couple of the other stock Directshow filters in the same DSP family and they work fine.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but it sounds promising! Thank you very much!

Comment: This answer is correct, perhaps it got voted down because the link directs to the Media Foundation documentation, and the question is tagged directshow, but the filter itself is a DMO filter, so it can be embedded in a DirectShow graph using the stock wrapper filter.  I am adding an answer to detail the steps needed.

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by Appleton is correct.  I am expanding on that answer, providing some sample code (in C++/CLI) showing how to instantiate the filter for a manually-built DirectShow graph (picking up the pieces from the available sparse documentation can be time-consuming).   The relevant code is inside the `REDUCE_FRAME_RATE` conditionally-compiled code. `COM_CALL()` is my custom HRESULT checking macro.

```
// Additional include files required for DMO support

#include <ParserUIDs.h>
#include <dmodshow.h>
#include <propsys.h>
    …

static void AddDecodedVideoSampleGrabber(
      AVStreamSourceBox^ sourceBox,
      IGraphBuilder* pGraph,
      CComPtr<IBaseFilter>& pDecodedVideoSampleGrabber,
      IPin* pSourcePin,
      CComPtr<IPin>& pDecodedVideoSampleGrabberOutPin
   ) {
      HRESULT hRes;

      COM_CALL(pDecodedVideoSampleGrabber.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SampleGrabber));
      COM_CALL(pGraph->AddFilter(pDecodedVideoSampleGrabber, L"DecodedVideoSampleGrabber"));
      CComPtr<IPin> pDecodedVideoSampleGrabberInPin(FilterTools::GetPin(pDecodedVideoSampleGrabber, "Input"));
      COM_CALL(pGraph->ConnectDirect(pSourcePin, pDecodedVideoSampleGrabberInPin, NULL));
      pDecodedVideoSampleGrabberOutPin = FilterTools::GetPin(pDecodedVideoSampleGrabber, "Output");

      auto pFrameCallbackSink = (SampleGrabberCBSink*)sourceBox->SetupSampleGrabberCallback(
         FRAME_SAMPLE_GRABBER,
         IntPtr(pDecodedVideoSampleGrabber)
      ).ToPointer();
      sourceBox->SetDecodedVideoSampleGrabber(IntPtr(pFrameCallbackSink));

   #ifdef REDUCE_FRAME_RATE
      // insert frame-reduction filter before x264 encoding  
      CComPtr<IBaseFilter> pFrameReducer;
      COM_CALL(pFrameReducer.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_DMOWrapperFilter));
      COM_CALL(pGraph->AddFilter(pFrameReducer, L"FrameReducer"));

      CComPtr<IDMOWrapperFilter> pDmoWrapper;
      COM_CALL(pFrameReducer->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDMOWrapperFilter), (void**)&pDmoWrapper));
      COM_CALL(pDmoWrapper->Init(__uuidof(CFrameRateConvertDmo), DMOCATEGORY_VIDEO_EFFECT));
      CComPtr<IPropertyStore> pPropStore;
      COM_CALL(pFrameReducer->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pPropStore)));

      PROPVARIANT var;
      PropVariantInit(&var);
      var.vt = VT_UI8;
      var.uhVal.HighPart = OUTPUT_FPS;    // Desired frame rate
      var.uhVal.LowPart = 1;
      pPropStore->SetValue(MFPKEY_CONV_OUTPUTFRAMERATE, var);
      PropVariantClear(&var);
      CComPtr<IPin>&pDmoInPin(FilterTools::GetPin(pFrameReducer, "in0"));
      COM_CALL(pGraph->ConnectDirect(pDecodedVideoSampleGrabberOutPin, pDmoInPin, NULL));
      CComPtr<IPin>&pDmoOutPin(FilterTools::GetPin(pFrameReducer, "out0"));
      pDecodedVideoSampleGrabberOutPin = pDmoOutPin;
   #endif

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own overlay filter and put it between the decoder and renderer. This filter should be able to accept to streams -> so two input pins. In case of the first stream it will just get the frame and apply the image overlay to it, generated by the second stream. So each time you will have one image stored in the overlay stream. The other solution is to use the third party overlay filters.

The second way to achieve this is by using the custom direct3d allocator presenter on VMR9 filter.In this way you will mix the images during the rendering in 3d environment. The second stream in this case will be implemented as a separated graph actually and as output must produce the bmp images by using the samplegrabber filter or your custom renderer. This way will produce a more flexible solution - you will be able to exchange you overlay videos whenever you need it.

Comment: I do have an overlay filter, I need a filter that adjusts the framerate of one of the streams.

Comment: But your overlay filter does not support streams with a different rates, that's the reason I mentioned about a new overlay filter implementation.

Comment: Sorry, didn't think of that! But the problem is that our core team has left the company and I am not very experienced with DirectShow, therefore I'd rather fall back to a third party filter! Thanks anyway!